# Cosmos DB Indexed search problems

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have a Cosmos DB with a collection with 134k documents and every document contains 2 string properties (named ChemicalName and EchNo) and 3 string collections (named CasNos, IndexNos and ReachNos).

Document JSON:

```
{
    "id": "9cb924ad-a100-4fce-9dc9-30ec968de585",
    "ChemicalName": "MyChemical",
    "EchaNumber": 1,
    "EcNo": "111-222-3",
    "CasNos": [
        "4444-55-6"
    ],
    "IndexNos": [
        "777-888-99-0"
    ],
    "ReachNos": [
        "01-0123456789-38-0000",
        "01-0123456789-38-0001",
        "01-0123456789-38-0002",
        "01-0123456789-38-0003",
        "01-0123456789-38-0004",
        "01-0123456789-38-0006",
        "01-0123456789-38-0007",
        "01-0123456789-38-0008",
        "01-0123456789-38-XXXX"
    ],
    "IndexScrapeDate": "2018-01-19T12:30:20.0404174Z",
    "ChemicalScrapeDate": null,
    "_rid": "96VvAOgIVwABAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/96VvAA==/colls/96VvAOgIVwA=/docs/96VvAOgIVwABAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00007e4d-0000-0000-0000-5a69b49b0000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1516876955
}
```

Collection have index definition:

```
  {
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
      {
        "path": "/*",
        "indexes": [
          {
            "kind": "Range",
            "dataType": "Number",
            "precision": -1
          },
          {
            "kind": "Hash",
            "dataType": "String",
            "precision": 3
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "path": "/EchaNumber/?",
        "indexes": [
          {
            "kind": "Range",
            "dataType": "Number",
            "precision": -1
          },
          {
            "kind": "Hash",
            "dataType": "String",
            "precision": 3
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "path": "/ChemicalName/?",
        "indexes": [
          {
            "kind": "Range",
            "dataType": "String",
            "precision": -1
          },
          {
            "kind": "Range",
            "dataType": "Number",
            "precision": -1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "path": "/CasNos/[]/?",
        "indexes": [
          {
            "kind": "Range",
            "dataType": "String",
            "precision": -1
          },
          {
            "kind": "Range",
            "dataType": "Number",
            "precision": -1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "path": "/EcNo/?",
        "indexes": [
          {
            "kind": "Range",
            "dataType": "String",
            "precision": -1
          },
          {
            "kind": "Range",
            "dataType": "Number",
            "precision": -1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "path": "/IndexNos/[]/?",
        "indexes": [
          {
            "kind": "Range",
            "dataType": "String",
            "precision": -1
          },
          {
            "kind": "Range",
            "dataType": "Number",
            "precision": -1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "path": "/ReachNos/[]/?",
        "indexes": [
          {
            "kind": "Range",
            "dataType": "String",
            "precision": -1
          },
          {
            "kind": "Range",
            "dataType": "Number",
            "precision": -1
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": []
  }
```

I implemented the code in Dotnet Core 2.0 and are using the SQL API.

When I search the collection I use the following SQL to find the ids of the docs I need:

```
SELECT VALUE c.id FROM IndexCollection c JOIN cas IN c.CasNos JOIN indx IN c.IndexNos WHERE CONTAINS(c.ChemicalName,"searchVal") OR STARTSWITH(cas,"searchVal") OR STARTSWITH(c.EcNo,"searchVal") OR STARTSWITH(indx,"searchVal")
```

I verified it by searching for a known partial match in CasNos string collection property.

I then needed to add search for ReachNos as well and added it to the search:

```
SELECT VALUE c.id FROM IndexCollection c JOIN cas IN c.CasNos JOIN indx IN c.IndexNos JOIN rch IN c.ReachNos WHERE CONTAINS(c.ChemicalName,"searchVal") OR STARTSWITH(cas,"searchVal") OR STARTSWITH(c.EcNo,"searchVal") OR STARTSWITH(indx,"searchVal") OR STARTSWITH(rch,"searchVal")
```

...But as soon as I add ReachNos to search it stops finding any result tho I use same searchval as above.
If I modify the SQL to only search the ReachNos property it will find results from that given I enter a known value from that property.

Can anyone pls. tell me why this is not working? 
I tried all combinations of the first SQL and no matter what properties I searched for it worked fine until I added ReachNos property.

EDIT: I should add I have tested on local Cosmos DB Emulator and azure.
EDIT2: Added document JSON

/Thanx

Comment: Would you please post your sample documents?

Comment: I added a sample JSON

Comment: thx.I'll do some tests.